# Huffman Encoding symbols with same probability

Tags: encoding, huffman-code

I'm doing exercises for a course about information transfer. We need to Huffman encode to a binary code alphabet.

The source alphabet has four symbols with probabilities:

- P(A) = 0.4
- P(B) = 0.3
- P(C) = 0.2
- P(D) = 0.1

So for Huffman I take the two symbols with the lowest probability, which are C and D in this example. I construct a subtree with two leaves (C & D).
The next symbol in the list, B, has a chance of 0.3.

There are two things I could do now. Either construct a second subtree with A & B, because the chance of B is the same as the value of the subtree CD. The second option is to put B with the subtree CD and create a bigger tree with value 0.6.

In the image below you see the two options I got. The first tree is making two subtrees and putting them together. The second tree is where we just insert B into the tree

[image: two trees]

My question now is what method should I choose? Make a new subtree for equal probability? Or put equal probabilities into the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have only one choice in the application Huffman's algorithm. At each step you must pick the *two* lowest probabilities. At the second step those are 0.3 (B) and 0.3 (C&D). You cannot use A at that step, since it has a higher probability of 0.4. So the first tree you drew is incorrect, in that it is not the result of applying Huffman's algorithm.

The second tree you drew is also incorrect. Or at least incorrectly drawn. A binary tree can have only two branches at any juncture. It cannot have three. The correct tree is A & (B & (C & D)).

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. And yeah, I thought there was something wring with my second tree! Thanks for pointing it out what is was!